# Divide parquet file on subfiles using fastparquet

Tags: python, csv, parquet, fastparquet

I need to convert a csv file to Parquet format. But this csv file is very huge (more than 65 000 rows and 1 000 columns), that's why I need to divide my parquet file into several subfiles by 5 000 rows and 200 columns in each one). I have already tried partition_on and row_group_offsets, but it doesn't work.

My code :

```
import pandas as pd
import fastparquet as fp

df = pd.read_csv('D:\Users\mim\Desktop\SI\LOG\LOG.csv')
fp.write(r'D:\Users\mim\Desktop\SI\newdata.parq', df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[CORRECT ANSWER] :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import fastparquet as fp

pathglobalcsv = 'D:\Users\mim\Desktop\SI'
inputFile = os.path.join(pathglobalcsv, 'LOG.csv')

table = pd.read_csv(inputFile, delimiter=';', chunksize=5000)
listrow = list(table)
columnCount = len(listrow[0])

fileCounter = 0

for row in listrow:
    for col in range(1, columnCount, 199):
        timestamp = row.ix[:, 0] #timestamp
        timestampcolumn = pd.DataFrame(timestamp)
        i=col+199
        maincols = row.ix[:, col:i] #other columns
        maincolumns = pd.DataFrame(maincols)
        outputDF = pd.concat([timestampcolumn, maincolumns], axis=1)

        #create a new file
        fileCounter += 1

        #parquet file
        fp.write(r'C:\Users\mim\eclipse-workspace\SI\file.part_' + str(fileCounter) + '.par', outputDF)
```